# IONIC 5 footer how to get rid of the bar above icons in the footer?

Tags: ionic-framework, button, icons, footer, ionic5

I would like to get rid of the bar above the icons in the footer.
Does someone know how to do it ? I didn't see anything about in the documentation.

My environment :

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.12
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.12
@angular/cli                  : 9.1.12
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.0
@capacitor/core : 2.4.0

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
native-run  : not installed

System:

NodeJS : v14.7.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm    : 6.14.7
OS     : macOS Catalina

HTML code :

```
<ion-footer class="ion-no-border" [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar transparent>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button  *ngIf="var=='sthing'" (click)="action()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="scan-sharp"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="toPage();" fill="clear">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="map"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

There`s nothing special in the scss file about ion-footer. The app uses native css component i think.

[Here is my footer with icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rhPM.png)

Thank you.
Bye.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To get help you need to share relevant code that helps others reproduce this issue. Please share the footer's template and relevant component code for this question.

Comment: Thank you, i just did what you asked for :)

Comment: thats good:) here is stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-yegirg?file=src/app/app.component.html I added your code but the issue is not reproducable;/

Comment: That's weird...thank you anyway..I didn't find out for the moment...

Comment: By the look at your screenshot I would "blame" a CSS class of some sort that adds a border-top styling to it. Like maybe from some extension even.